# WPF Globalization (Perhaps Not)

Tags: c#, wpf, globalization

I am trying to build an prototype with labels, buttons, and so on. However, I do want the text in the labels or buttons to be customized through an external files, perhaps a text file or excel file. How can I achieve this?

Currently, I am trying on using a CSV file as in the following format.

Dashboard Title, Dashboard
Box 1 Column Name, Box 1
Button 1, Next

And in my codes, I read them into the text field as follows.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("Dashboard.csv");
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    string currentLine = lines[i];
    string[] lineValues = currentLine.Split(',');
    switch (i)
    {
        case 0: dashboardTitle.Content = lineValues[1];
        case 1: box1ColName.Content = lineValues[1];
        case 2: button1.Content = lineValues[1];
    }
}
```

My worry now is that as the number of fields (elements) grow. I would have to extends the switch part perhaps up to case 100? How can I specify them perhaps in the CSV file to fill in the lable, buttons accordingly?

Comment: wrong approeach, use resource DLL's instead.

Comment: @Flawless, correct me if I am wrong. I don't want to use DLL as I would like the 'end-user' to easily customize the 'wording' of the label by using text editor or Excel. Or is this achievable in using resource DLL?

Comment: Therefore you need slightly more than a text editor. :) But applications for i18n do have a very powerful set of features. You can e.g. resize the controls if the text doesn't fit. We usually use Visual Localize for those exercies.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a name = value format in your file.

```
e.g.
```

button1 = "My name is button1"
   label2 = "This is a label"

Load these values into a dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>();    
d.Add("button1", "My name is button1");    
d.Add("label2", "This is a label");
```

You can then do the following algorithm. Loop through all the components on your form. If the component name matches the dictionary key, set the appropriate value. e.g.:

```
  Control.ControlCollection coll = this.Controls;
  foreach(Control c in coll) 
  {
    if(c != null)
    {
       if (d.ContainsKey(c.Name))
       {
         c.Text = d[c.Name];
       }
    }
  }
```

Another way of finding controls is using the:
    Control.ControlCollection.Find 
method. Its much easier to search for controls by name.

Note however, that not all controls will have a ".Text" property, so you have to check for the type of control.
However, I would also strongly suggest you learn how to use resource files. Its a commonly accepted way of handling resource strings.

Answer (score 0):

Scott Hanselman has just recently written a blog post that might fit to you. It was written with ASP.NET as an example, but it is explicitely not limited to it:

[Globalization, Internationalization and Localization in ASP.NET MVC 3, JavaScript and jQuery - Part 1](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CategoryView.aspx?category=Internationalization)

This starts a nine-page long article about the topic.